# ObjectMapper readValue Type Convert From LinkedHasMap to Custom Type

Tags: java

I have a statement below which gives me list of Objects which are of Type LinkedHashMap.

```
List<MyCustomClassA> optionsList = mapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(OtherClassA.getItems()), List.class);
```

**MyCustomClassA**

```
@Data
@Builder
public class MyCustomClassA {
    private Boolean disabled;
    private Boolean selected;
    private String text;
    private String value;
}
```

But the value that `optionsList` iterate are the type of `LinkedHashMap`. `OtherClassA.getItems()` returns the `List<MyCustomClassB>`

**MyCustomClassB**

```
public class MyCustomClassB {
    private String text;
    private String value;
    Private List<Images> imageList;
}
```

What I am  looking to achieve to get `optionsList` which should be of type `MyCustomClassA`.

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Show your whole code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are not providing the exact `TypeReference` that json string need to be deserialized. Since you provided raw type list `List.class` objectmapper treats it as `List<Object>`. And you are deserializing `JsonArray` of `JsonObject`, so `ObjectMapper` converts into `List<LinkedHashMap>` because `JsonObject` represents and implements `Map`

```
List<MyCustomClassA> optionsList = objectMapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(OtherClassA.getItems()), new TypeReference<List<MyCustomClassA>>(){});
```

And also you need to add `@NoArgConstructor` and `@AllArgConstructor` annotation on `MyCustomClassA` because lombok `@Data` will only bundles the features of `@ToString`, `@EqualsAndHashCode`, `@Getter / @Setter` and `@RequiredArgsConstructor`

Comment: I have tried the same, but getting error something like **Cannot construct instance of `MyCustomClassA` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)**

Comment: is that the complete class? can you please provide complete class `MyCustomClassA` ? @zdhim

Comment: Updated in question.

Comment: try my answer with `@NoArgConstructor`

Comment: I believe you should have `@AllArgsConstructor` as well. Or use `@Value` instead of `@Data` and make all fields final.

Comment: I used only @NoArgConstructor, which given me error something like **Error:(9) java: constructor MyCustomClassA in class com.MyCustomClassA cannot be applied to given types;** Then I tried **@NoArgConstructor** along with **@AllArgsConstructor** which fixed the issue. Thanks